# What to do if a question is crossposted from a non-StackExchange website?

Tags: discussion, questions, plagiarism

This question:

[Are blood vessels organs?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/34397/are-blood-vessels-organs)

Is clearly copied from:

https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080703182004AA2NPRi

It sure is a good idea to ask questions and get answers, but how should it be treated? Is this acceptable?

Comment: Voting to re-open. Copying a question from somewhere is different to copying an answer.

Comment: @JonW It doesn't matter whether it's a question or an answer.  Content is content.  Plagiarized content is plagiarized content and should be treated the same way.

Comment: @Servy That may well be true, but there is a logical distinction between wondering the same thing that someone else once did, and stealing someone else's knowledge and representing it as your own. Two different questions, but maybe with related answers.

Comment: @JonW How is that any different between questions and answers?  Two people can provide the same general answer to a given question without plagiarizing each other, in the same way that two people can ask the same general question without plagiarizing each other, just as they can actually copy the works and have it be plagiarism.  I see nothing different about questions than answers.

Answer (score 6):

Disclaimer: I'm not a lawyer ....

Reading the [Stack Exchange Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) it states in chapter 3, subscriber content:

> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license

If that post is allowed based on the Terms of Service depends on the license of [Yahoo Answers](https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/terms/utos/index.htm) which reads in Chapter 9, sub c:

> With respect to Content other than photos, graphics, audio or video you submit or make available for inclusion on publicly accessible areas of the Yahoo Services other than Yahoo Groups, the perpetual, irrevocable and fully sublicensable license to use, distribute, reproduce, modify, adapt, publish, translate, publicly perform and publicly display such Content (in whole or in part) and to incorporate such Content into other works in any format or medium now known or later developed.

I conclude that Yahoo answers legally allows the content to be published else where.

On to the non-legal part: **Is it acceptable?**

I think it is acceptable if you are looking for better answers.
However I don't find it acceptable (never!) that you copy  a question (or answers for that matter) without attribution, or indication that it is not your own work you are posting, whatever lawyers or licenses says. I expect such copied questions to include why the current answers given on the other resource doesn't answer the question. In that way the post adds value and implements implicitly the advice from my last paragraph.

If you find users copying stuff, either leave a comment so the OP can add the proper attribution, (suggest an) edit to add the proper attribution (both source and original author) or flag for a moderator if by copying the license of the original material is breached.